# Pointer to Pointer as function parameter for a getter

Tags: c++, pointers

Given some struct:

```
struct Foo {
  // ...
};
```

I want to use a function from a lib with the following signature:

```
void getAllFoos(Foo** foos);
```

Basically, the function should return a vector of all Foos, but someone decided to use the pointer-to-pointer for the purpose of returning something. I have to give some sort of empty Foo** to the function, so it can be filled.

How do I initialize `foos` when I want to call that function? Will a "null-pointer" (Foo**) be sufficient, or do I have to get the amount of foos first and malloc enough memory myself (how do I do that for a pointer-to-pointer?)? And who is responsible for freeing the memory?

Comment: A vector and pointer to pointer are not compatible, do you mean an array of `Foos`?

Comment: How do you know how many Foos return? How about C++ list/vector and shared pointers ?

Comment: The signature `void getAllFoos(Foo** foos);` suggests, that the function wants the address of a `Foo*` so it can allocate memory for the user: `Foo *foos; getAllFoos(&foos);`

Comment: If the function allocates for some number of `struct Foo`, then "Yes" you can initially set `struct Foo *myptr = NULL;` in the caller and your function `getAllFoos` takes the *address of* `myptr` as a parameter and can allocate and set the address of the original pointer which will then be visible back in the caller.

Comment: @Swordfish: if it was the case, wouldn't the function return the size of the allocated array?

Comment: Please limit your question to \*one\* language. C \*or\* C++. In C the function declaration as shown is a syntax error.

Comment: We need the definition of getAllFoos to know what it expects.  Swordfish's guess is *probably* correct, but we can't know that for sure without seeing the code.

Comment: @Ray Thats why i didn't write an answer ;)

Comment: @papagaga It probably should, but since it does not i suspect it will place an element signaling the end of the block last.

Comment: What `getAllFoos` is doing exactly? Returns already existing array of pointers or creates it or copy to it? Why the array length is not specified as a second parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`foos` does not need to be initialized** if `getAllFoos` can be assumed to work something like this -- it will initialize `foos` it for you:

```
void getAllFoos(Foo** pfoos) {
    Foo* the_pointer_to_all_the_foos;
    // (1) maybe the_pointer_to_all_the_foos = malloc(10 * sizeof(Foo));
    // (2) maybe the_pointer_to_all_the_foos = new Foo[10];
    // (3) maybe the_pointer_to_all_the_foos is a static Foo[10]
    *pfoos = the_pointer_to_all_the_foos;
}
```

With the API above, there is no reason for `getallFoos` to read the value of `pfoos`.

To use it:

```
// in C, you should write: struct Foo* foos;
Foo* foos;
getAllFoos(&foos); // note: foos is Foo*, pfoos is Foo**
```

In general, the API documentation for `getAllFoos` **must** document what you need to do with `foos` in the end. Depending on what the code does [`(1)`, `(2)`, `(3)` from above or something else], you might need to `free(foos)`, `delete[] foos`, do nothing, or do something else. We cannot answer that with the information given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should call that function by passing reference of pointer of type `struct Foo`.

```
struct Foo *foo = NULL;
getAllFoos(&foo);
```

You can free `foo` as below

`free(foo); //Assuming getAllFoos allocated the memory and filled.`

---

> Will a "null-pointer" (Foo**) be sufficient

No `FOO *` should point to valid memory.

`struct Foo **foo = NULL;
 getAllFoos(foo);`

If `getAllFoos` tries to dereference `foo` You will have undefined behavior.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I believe what kiranBiradar tried to say with *FOO * should point to valid memory.* is that the parameter `foo` derecerenced once shouldn't be `NULL`.

Comment: Maybe you can reformulate your answer so it is clearer. Also, *passing reference* is a little misleading. `&foo` takes the address of `foo` and passes it as a value to `getAllFoos()`. No references involved.

Comment: So the answer was to simply say that "If it was NULL and the function dreferenced it -- then that would cause problems? I'll give it the benefit of the doubt, but I read the answer so say "NO you can't pass `*foos` as a `NULL` pointer. So I guess at best it was unclear either way. (I didn't ding for it -- so no harm there)

Comment: I see it the other way now, thanks @Swordfish, above the horizontal he is talking about `struct Foo *foo = NULL;`, below he is taking about an initial setting of `struct Foo **foo = NULL;` (and that is presumably in the caller) and then yes, I agree in part, NOT that "FOO * should point to valid memory." but that FOO * should have a valid address." (i.e. that it is a valid declared pointer itself)

Comment: All we came up with is speculation about OPs function at best. For all we know the function could set the passed pointer to the first node of a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know in advance how many `Foo`'s you're going to get. There is no getting around this if you get all the `Foo`s at once, and this is hard-wired in the interface. What you can do, though, if you're responsible for allocating memory, is to use a `std::vector` as a recipient, and give its `data()` member as an argument:

```
std::vector<Foo> flexible_buffer(Foo_nb); // or reserve later
getAllFoos(&(flexible_buffer.data());
```

Comment: if the function allocates memory somehow and tries to modify the pointer you pass it all hell breaks loose

Comment: *You need to know in advance how many Foo's you're going to get. There is no getting around this* Yes, there is. But without knowing which function of which library that is, its all guesswork.